# How I can provide a Collection at the constructor of my Graphql Resolver?

Tags: magento2.4, magento-graphql

In my module I defined a `etc/schema.graphqls`:

```
type BlogPost {
    blog_post_id: ID
    title: String
    post: String
}

input BlogpostAttributeFilterInput {
    page: Int
    limit: Int
}

type Query {
    allBlogPosts(input: BlogpostAttributeFilterInput) :
    [BlogPost] @resolver(class: "\\MageGuide\\FirstModule\\Model\\Resolver\\GetBlogPosts")
    @doc(description:"Retrieve All BlogPosts")
    @cache(cacheable: false)
}
```

And I made the following resolver:

```
namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\Resolver;

use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost;
use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPost\Collection as BlogPosts;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class GetBlogPosts implements ResolverInterface
{

    private BlogPosts $collection;

    public function __construct(BlogPosts $collection){
        $this->collection=$collection;
    }
    public function resolve(   Field $field,
                                     $context,
                               ResolveInfo $info,
                               array $value = null,
                               array $args = null)
    {

        // @TODO Get page and limit from graphql
        $page = 1;
        $limit = 10;

        $results = $this->collection
                ->setPageSize($limit)
                ->setCurPage($page)
                ->addOrder('creation_dt','DESC');

        return $results->getItems()->toArray();
    }
}
```

That depends upon the following model:

```
namespace MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPost;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\BlogPost as Model;
use MageGuide\FirstModule\Model\ResourceModel\BlogPostResource as ResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Model::class, ResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

But once I do my request:

```
{
    allBlogPosts{
        blog_post_id
    title
        post
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "allBlogPosts"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "debugMessage": "Typed property MageGuide\\FirstModule\\Model\\Resolver\\GetBlogPosts::$collection must not be accessed before initialization"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "allBlogPosts": null
    }
}
```

Does that mean that I need to modify the `di.xml` in order the collection to be provided as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ensure that the object key "collection" is always refered with the same characters (copy paste them to be sure)

and change

`return $results->getItems()->toArray();`

to

`return $results->load()->getData();`